# the meaning of "a single curl, the colour of onion-skin, peeps out from under a lopsided crown"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Jo brings him an Easter egg. ‘Look, we have saved this one for you.’
>   It is a white egg with no speckles. It is featureless, **but a single
>   curl, the colour of onion-skin, peeps out from under a lopsided crown**.
>   You pick your prince and you know what he is: or do you?
>
> — Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel

Does the sentence describe that the egg Jo brings is decorated with a crown and a white blond hair like curl under the crown?

Comment: A (yellow) onion's outer skin is a pale orangy-brown. The clue is in the verb "peeps".

Comment: So a pale oranage-brown color strand of curly hair sticks out from the crown?  Do you decorate Easter eggs like this?

Comment: It would not be terribly odd to decorate an Easter egg with a crown; I think the bolded phrase probably is describing the decoration.

Comment: The novel is set over 400 years ago, so how I might decorate Easter eggs is probably not going to shed light on this passage. What color hair did Henry have?

Comment: I googled and found that Henry's hair was red. I guess the onion skin color curl represents Henry's hair. I was able to picture the egg except the color of the curl. It was just that I couldn't be sure about my image of the egg because I've never seen an Easter egg decorated like that. Thank you.

Comment: My first thought was that the egg is hatching. The crown is the cracked eggshell. The curl is the chick's feathers. Maybe?

Comment: The type of onion I call a 'salad onion' has red skin. Google 'red onion' to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The passage describes the decoration. The curl is either hair or something that is meant to look like hair (like twine or straw). The color is probably a yellow-brown, since yellow onion skins have been used to make dye of this color for hundreds of years. In the context of the story, calling something "onion-skin colored" could even be taken literally, i.e. if is colored with onion skin dye. The color could have conceivably referred to a red onion, but I'm not sure they were available at that place and time.

The egg is meant to look like a prince, with his hair sticking out under from under his crown. The crown may have been made of wood, paper, or some kind of fabric.